# ReactiveUI Change observable notifications has strange order

Tags: c#, observable, reactiveui

I have an ReactiveObject:

```
public class Example : ReactiveObject
{
    private string _commonProperty;
    public string CommonProperty
    {
        get { return _commonProperty; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _commonProperty, value); }
    }

    private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<string> _dependent;
    public string DependentProperty => _dependent.Value;

    public Example()
    {
        _dependent = this.WhenAnyValue(e => e.CommonProperty)
            .Select(s => s?.ToUpper())
            .ToProperty(this, e => e.DependentProperty);
    }
}
```

And when I change value of CommonProperty, order of PropertyChanged events and Changed observable items are not same.

For example:

```
var example = new Example();
example.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine("Event: " + args.PropertyName);
example.Changed.Subscribe(args => Console.WriteLine("Changed Observable: " + args.PropertyName));
example.CommonProperty = "newValue";
```

Prints

```
Event: CommonProperty
Event: DependentProperty
Changed Observable: DependentProperty
Changed Observable: CommonProperty
```

Events has expected order, but Changed observable is not.
So the question is why *Changed Observable: DependentProperty* comes before *Changed Observable: CommonProperty*?

And moreover, I expect output like this:

```
Event: CommonProperty
Changed Observable: CommonProperty
Event: DependentProperty
Changed Observable: DependentProperty
```

Why events and observable notifications about same property are separated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is important, and I certainly wouldn't rely on it. It's just an implementation detail.

From a quick look at the source code for RxUI 6, raising of the property changed event ultimately ends up at [this method call](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/rxui6-master/ReactiveUI/IReactiveObject.cs#L270):

```
public void raisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (!this.areChangeNotificationsEnabled())
        return;

    var changed = new ReactivePropertyChangedEventArgs<TSender>(sender, propertyName);
    sender.RaisePropertyChanged(changed);

    this.notifyObservable(sender, changed, this.changedSubject);
}
```

So you can probably deduce from this how you end up with the order of events you are seeing.  Each of these happens in order, and each is written to the console by your subscribers:

1. You change `CommonProperty`, which calls `raisePropertyChanged("CommonProperty")`, which then raises the event using `sender.RaisePropertyChanged`.
2. This event causes `DependentProperty` to be re-computed, which results in a call to `raisePropertyChanged("DependentProperty")`, which raises the event as above.
3. `notifyObservable` is then called for `DependentProperty`.  This pushes `changed` through the `Changed` observable.
4. Then control returns to `raisePropertyChanged` for `CommonProperty` and  `notifyObservable` is called for `CommonProperty`.

Comment: Thanks! I absolutely agree I should not rely on it. I just expected that order of events and observable's notifications will be the same, and when it's not, I assumed that I doing something wrong.